# Rewriting DRF token auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I wanted to allow a user to have multiple tokens so decided to rewrite the Token model. As result created

```
class TokenAuthentication(rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication):
    model = Token
```

In my settings added to `REST_FRAMEWORK`

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'users.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
)
```

Also modified

```
class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        name = serializer.validated_data['name']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user, name=name)
        return Response({'token': token.key})


obtain_auth_token = ObtainAuthToken.as_view()
```

and AuthTokenSerializer to return the name

Finaly in the urls got

```
url(r'^token-auth/', obtain_auth_token),
```

I think all is correct but keep getting the errors

```
 File "/home/me/code/python/OCManager/core/users/authentication.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
ImportError: cannot import name 'APIView'
```

and

```
ImportError: Could not import 'users.authentication.TokenAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ImportError: cannot import name 'APIView'.
```

Any hint what it could be?

The Token class modification is this:

```
class Token(rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token):
    # key is no longer primary key, but still indexed and unique
    key = models.CharField(_("Key"), max_length=40, db_index=True, unique=True)
    # relation to user is a ForeignKey, so each user can have more than one token
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='auth_tokens',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("User")
    )
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'name'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " - " + self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find what was wrong. Having the TokenAuth extension in the same file was causing some import error, seems trying to import itself in other file. The solution was moving

```
class TokenAuthentication(rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication):
    model = Token
```

to another file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've imported `TokenAuthentication` from `rest_framework.authentication` and not from `rest_framework.authToken`

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this error FOREVER. It turned out to have to do with tokens like everyone else was saying. This isn't exactly a "fix" but it got rid of the error for me:

I was using simplejwt and commented out the import:
`from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken`
And also commented out the function using the import.

My error was resolved after this.